# How can I redirect only specific subdomains to HTTPS in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Say I have 3 subdomains, `sub1`, `sub2`, and `sub3`. I want to redirect all HTTP requests to `sub1` and `sub2` to use HTTPS, but I do not want `sub3` to do any redirects.

I initially had the following when I had just `sub1` and `sub2` setup, which worked fine, but since I have `sub3` now and it cannot be directed to HTTPS, it doesn't work anymore:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://${HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a condition to check for domain name:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(?:sub1|sub2)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```